# Webscraping error in Python: How can I write "don't scrape it if the page in the loop does not have a text"

Tags: python, web-scraping

While I am running the loop for scraping the page, I got the error like this

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div"}   (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.177)
```

And I saw the webpage, and that one does not have any text, which is the reason why it got errored.

How can I write a code that neglect this kind of non-text webpage?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just wrap this piece of code in try statement:

```
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div")
except:
    print("No text.")
```